# Modify remote driver URL at runtime

Tags: selenium, serenity-bdd, testcontainers

I have a project which is based on the [serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber-starter](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber-starter) project. I'm using [test-containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) to start a couple of Docker containers as well as a `Selenium Grid` container to run the test against.

```
new GenericContainer<>(SELENIUM_IMAGE)
            ...
            .withExposedPorts(SELENIUM_CONTAINER_PORT, SELENIUM_CONTAINER_NOVNC_PORT)
            ...
);
```

When the tests start, `test-containers` will ramp up the containers and bind random host ports to all exposed ports of the containers.

Because of that, I cannot define a fixed value in `serenity.conf` for the url of the remote driver

```
webdriver.remote.url = "http://localhost:????/wd/hub"
```

Thus I need a way to set `webdriver.remote.url` programmatically.

One option would be to use the `FixedHostPortGenericContainer`, which allows you define the host port on which the container exposed port will be bound to.

I'd rather would like to use a different approach though, as the developers state that

> While this works, we strongly advise against using fixed ports, since this will automatically lead to integrated tests (which are an anti pattern).

So the question is: How can I modify the value of `webdriver.remote.url` at runtime? Is there any option provided by `serenity-bdd` to reload the `net.thucydides.core.util.SystemEnvironmentVariables` at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced recently the same issue, but was lucky enough to find a solution:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.FirefoxDriverCapabilities;
import net.thucydides.core.guice.Injectors;
import net.thucydides.core.util.EnvironmentVariables;
import net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverSource;

public class CustomWebDriverFactory implements DriverSource {

    @Override
    public WebDriver newDriver() {
        try {
            String ip = "your_dynamic_ip";
            return new RemoteWebDriver(
                    new URL("http://" + ip + ":4444/wd/hub"),
                    new FirefoxDriverCapabilities(Injectors.getInjector().getProvider(EnvironmentVariables.class).get()).getCapabilities());
    }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean takesScreenshots() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So you have to add such factory implementation and define in **serenity.properties**:

```
webdriver.driver = provided
webdriver.provided.type = mydriver
webdriver.provided.mydriver = <your_factory_package>.CustomWebDriverFactory
thucydides.driver.capabilities = mydriver
```